# Java NIO - gracefully closing connection on the client side

Tags: java, sockets, nio

When using NIO, I have the following checks on the server side:

```
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                readBuffer.clear();
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                int read = channel.read(readBuffer);
                if (read == -1) {
                    channel.close();
                    channel.keyFor(selector).cancel();
                } else {
                    readBuffer.flip();
                    System.out.println(charset.decode(readBuffer));
                }
            }
```

However, it is often the case that read will throw `java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. On the client side, this is what I do to close the connection:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    connection.close();
    connection.keyFor(selector).cancel();
    selector.close();
}
```

If that is not the graceful way, what is?

Comment: You don't need to cancel the key after closing the channel. It happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The server should send a message to the client to close its connection.  It can only do this if the buffers are not full, but it will allows the client to gracefully close the connection.

A simpler solution is for the client to expect this exception and handle it silently.  However, the poison pill message is more reliable IMHO as you can tell whether the connection was intended to be closed by the server.

BTW The client can send the same message to the server.  After sending the message, you might want to wait for the other end to hang up before closing the connection yourself (or timing out)

Comment: So I would send a message from the client to the server stating I am no longer sending any messages so that the server can remove the connection on its side from the selector, therefore not hitting the `Exception`, is that right? If that is the case, what is the purpose of `-1` result on the read method on channel? When is this condition happening?

Comment: The -1 means the output stream was closed before the socket.  If you just close the socket, it does it more forcefully ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey No it doesn't. It still sends a FIN and yields a -1 to the peer read() method. The only difference is that closing the socket loses any data buffered in the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception if you have written to the connection after the peer had already closed it. In other words, an application protocol error.

Solution: don't.

Comment: I don'tsee how that is the case. The client on his side awaits for the WRITE op on its own selector and writes a message e.g. 100 times. Then it simply closes the connection. The server only reads the incoming messages fomr clients, but it still sees the channelas read-ready when this exception happens... WHy?